# Как организовать данные, чтобы из одного js скрипта можно было получить переменные в другом?

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, frontend

Есть сайт. В нём 2 страницы с блоками программ обучения и одна страница с записью на обучение, в которой есть форма select, выводящая названия программ. (пока ещё нет)).

У каждой из страниц с программами есть свой скрипт, который создаёт массив с названиями. Мне нужно эти данные каким-либо образом передать на страницу записи. Там я уже смогу с ними оперировать.

Очень прошу помочь с данной ситуацией, так как пишу сюда от безысходности.

Начинал ход мыслей с import-ов, но я не могу превратить скрипты в модули. (если есть предложения как это организовать с помощью них - я открыт)
Потом пробовал local/sessionStorage, но мне нужно, чтобы юзер сразу заходил на страницу записи и видел доступные программы, а не заходил сначала на страницы с ними, чтобы названия сохранились у него.
В итоге дошёл до ajax-а, так как посчитал, что это лучший из возможных методов. Я бы хотел, чтобы  у меня в файлах где-то лежал programms.json (да бог с ним, даже txt), и с него читались программы. Но столкнулся с проблемой, что я никак не могу вносить в него изменения. Поэтому пишу сюда и невероятно надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: Почему нельзя эти 2 скрипта объединить в один или подкючить оба к каждой странице?

Comment: @SwaD Потому что в скриптах происходит работа с DOM. Если я сделаю все действия в одном скрипте, то во первых - нарушится корректность создания массива с названиями программ и во вторых если я запущу данный скрипт на странице с записью на обучение, то он не сможет получить данные с других страниц, в этом то и проблема.

Comment: c import/export не получается, так как в скриптах происходит заполнение массива значениями заголовков ( document.querySelector('....') );
и когда запускается скрипт, в котором происходит импорт, то он переходит к экспортирующему скрипту и выполняет его, но берёт значения не того html к которому тот привязан, а своего собственного. 
Мне кажется я скоро сойду с ума...

Comment: Можете привести минимальный воспроизводимый пример того, чего пытаетесь достичь? У меня пока есть ощущение, что на ваших страницах, как в HTML, так и в JS есть дубликаты кода и дубликаты id DOM элементов, что и приводит к ошибке. Однако так же стоит помнить, что при переходе на вторую страницу, все перегружается и данные из памяти будут удалены(Если это именно 2 физически разные страницы).

Comment: Воспроизводимого примера нет, я в первую очередь и написал сюда, чтобы понять - возможно ли такое вообще реализовать. Дубликатов классов DOM элементов нет, пишу по БЭМ. Ошибка заключается в том, что после импортирования, элемент (который был неправильно задан) равен null